# Jupyter Notebook is showing No pyspark kernel upon startup

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, kernel, ipython

I am running pyspark scripts in jupyter notebook but the kernel is not starting. upon selecting pyspark from the dropdown the kernel loads and remains busy for some time and then shows "no kernel".

Can someone help me?

Note: upon running "$Jupyter kernelspec list" i can see pyspark kernel in the list.

Comment: Any console output?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved only by re configuring the Jupyter notebook.